# Find which using directives are used in method

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How can I know which using directives are used in the descendants of a given SyntaxNode.

See the following example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCzNST
Here I want to know which usings are used in Class1, but ignore the usings that are used in Class2.

Comment: That's actually far more complicated than you think; removing seemingly-unrelated `using` directives can affect overload resolution in complicated cases with lambdas.

Comment: I don't want to remove usings. I just want to know which usings definitally are being used.

Comment: @SLaks' point is that "definitely used" is hard, since overload resolution depends on subtle ways on the list of usings. If the heuristic of "bind the types and make a list" is good enough for your use, that's fine. But be aware it is a heuristic. In the Roslyn architecture the compiler directly generates the unused using information for us because you can't do it with the APIs we provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the types relevant to the Syntax Nodes using the semantic model. The type info knows the related namespace which you can use to identify the relevant usings. When iterating through all nodes you receive the return values of methods as well as the types of variables, properties and fields. If you restrict the nodes to a specific type (e.g. InvocationExpressionSyntax) you only get return types, variable types, etc.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindUsedUsings(SemanticModel model, SyntaxNode node)
{
    var resultList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var identifier in node.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
    {
        var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(identifier);
        if (typeInfo.Type != null)
        {
            resultList.Add(typeInfo.Type.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString());
        }
    }
    return resultList.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

However if you wish to obtain the usings you have to identify all declared types. I wrote an (incomplete) solution to identify three types of required usings:

```
using System;
using Text = System.String;
using static System.Console;
```

You can identify every type of using with a different logic.

For the first type of using you should consider:

- var requires no using
- PredefinedTypes (string, int) require no using
- dynamic requires no using
- QualifiedTypeNames require no using

For the second type of using you should consider:

- While a type can be resolved using the alias you can also use the original name. Using the example from above, you could write the Statement string sample = Text.Empty;

For the third type of using you do not have an Identifier for the type, therefore you need to find the call using the Expression Statement.
Note that in the solution below a using static MyNamespace.Classname will not be resolved correctly as I was provided no TypeSymbol for the method's IdentifierNameSyntax so I couldn't resolve the type.

This can resolve in two problems:

- If the type is not resolved a using static MyNamespace.Classname might be missing when analyzing the class MyNamespace.Class2
- If the type is resolved an invalid using static MyNamespace.Classname might be present when analyzing the class MyNamespace.Classname (as the type name is not required within the class itself.

With that in mind here is the solution I came up with. There may be further special cases to consider, however I think it is a nice starting point:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindUsedUsings(SemanticModel model, 
            SyntaxNode node, SyntaxNode root)
{
    var aliasResolution = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var usings = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>();
    foreach (var curr in usings)
    {
        var nameEquals = curr.DescendantNodes().
            OfType<NameEqualsSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (nameEquals != null)
        {
            var qualifiedName =
                curr.DescendantNodes().OfType<QualifiedNameSyntax>().
                    FirstOrDefault()?.ToFullString();
            if (qualifiedName != null)
            {
                aliasResolution.Add(nameEquals.Name.Identifier.Text, qualifiedName);
            }
        }
    }
    var currentNamespace = node.Ancestors().
        OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
    var namespacename = currentNamespace?.Name.ToString();
    if (namespacename == null)
    {
        // Empty namespace
        namespacename = string.Empty;
    }
    var resultList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var identifier in node.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<TypeSyntax>())
    {
        if (identifier is PredefinedTypeSyntax || identifier.IsVar)
        {
            // No usings required for predefined types or var... 
            // [string, int, char, var, etc. do not need usings]
            continue;
        }
        // If an alias is defined use it prioritized
        if (GetUsingFromAlias(model, identifier, aliasResolution, resultList))
        {
            continue;
        }
        // If a type is provided, try to resolve it
        if (GetUsingFromType(model, identifier, namespacename, resultList))
        {
            continue;
        }
        // If no type is provided check if the expression 
        // corresponds to a static member call
        GetUsingFromStatic(model, identifier, resultList);
    }
    return resultList.Distinct().ToList();
}

private static void GetUsingFromStatic(SemanticModel model, TypeSyntax identifier, 
            List<string> resultList)
{
    var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(identifier).Symbol;
    // If the symbol (field, property, method call) can be resolved, 
    // is static and has a containing type
    if (symbol != null && symbol.IsStatic && symbol.ContainingType != null)
    {
        var memberAccess = identifier.Parent as ExpressionSyntax;
        if (memberAccess != null)
        {
            bool hasCallingType = false;
            var children = memberAccess.ChildNodes();
            foreach (var childNode in children)
            {
                // If the Expression has a Type 
                // (that is, if the expression is called from an identifyable source)
                // no using static is required
                var typeInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(childNode).Symbol as INamedTypeSymbol;
                if (typeInfo != null)
                {
                    hasCallingType = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if the type-Info is missing a static using is required
            if (!hasCallingType)
            {
                // type three using: using static [QualifiedType]
                resultList.Add($"static {symbol.ContainingType}");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool GetUsingFromType(SemanticModel model, TypeSyntax identifier, 
            string namespacename, List<string> resultList)
{
    var typeInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(identifier).Symbol as INamedTypeSymbol;
    // dynamic is not required and not provided as an INamedTypeSymbol
    if (typeInfo != null)
    {
        if (identifier is QualifiedNameSyntax 
            || identifier.Parent is QualifiedNameSyntax)
        {
            // Qualified namespaces can be ignored...
            return true;
        }
        var containingNamespace = typeInfo.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
        // The current namespace need not be referenced
        if (namespacename == containingNamespace)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Type one using: using [Namespace];
        resultList.Add(typeInfo.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool GetUsingFromAlias(SemanticModel model, TypeSyntax identifier, 
            Dictionary<string, string> aliasResolution, List<string> resultList)
{
    var aliasInfo = model.GetAliasInfo(identifier);
    // If the identifier is an alias
    if (aliasInfo != null)
    {
        // check if it can be resolved
        if (aliasResolution.ContainsKey(aliasInfo.Name))
        {
            // Type two using: using [Alias] = [QualifiedType];
            resultList.Add($"{aliasInfo.Name} = {aliasResolution[aliasInfo.Name]}");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This particular code will catch types that are being "used" in some ways. It's a question for the original poster (that's not clear) that if I do something like "var x = y.z", are we considering `x`'s namepace to be "used" or not. I guess if they are trying to have some sort of rule of "layer X can't touch layer Y" then your code is a great start. But they _might_ want something else.

Comment: What I want is simple: I want to know which usings are necessary to run that piece of code. If you remove that using, an error will appear in that code piece.

Comment: The code in the current answer is not what I expect, it simply returns all used namespaces. When the syntaxnode for example contains "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)" your list will contain "System.Threading", but in that case no using is necessary. It's in the next step that I'm getting stuck.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that. I guess you could find the types with the appropriate SyntaxNodes, however that would require a lot of different logic and knowledge about the where a type might be used. Furthermore you would probably have problems identifying extension methods and similar constructs.